# Converting coordinates from cartesian to geodetic in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, coordinates, latitude-longitude, xy

I have a problem with my layer attributes in QGIS, every time I add `$x` and `$y` coordinates as attributes, they are always returned to me in meters, while I would need this data expressed in degrees.

I changed the properties of the project in Project > Properties > General > Show coordinates in use > Geographical map (degrees), but nothing changed.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is crs of the layer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Show coordinates in use` option is for visualization purposes. It doesn't affect the expression.

You need to transform. Use this for X:

```
x(transform($geometry, @layer_crs, 'EPSG:4326'))
```

and for Y:

```
y(transform($geometry, @layer_crs, 'EPSG:4326'))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much works perfectly! is there a way to set the ddegrees as the default output?

Comment: I don't think there is. But I am unsure though. Expressions use the layer's crs.